# C++ getline segmentation fault, std::vector<custom class>

Tags: c++, ifstream, stdvector, getline

I've been looking at this for a while in the debugger while Googling around, but I think I've stumbled upon some C++ behavior that I'm not familiar with. I'm going to give a quick outline on what I'm doing and what/where the problem is. I'll put code block below.

The rough outline of what's happening is:

1. Created a custom class (LogReader) to handle a single log file.
2. LogReader contains a pointer to an ifstream (ifstream *log_file)
3. The ifstream is used with getline() in the constructor, this works fine.
4. The LogReader is placed in a vector.

   - The code below for main.cpp is using the LogReader directly (without the vector). The segfault occurs in both cases.
5. LogReader.advance() is called. getline() is used in this function. The segfault occurs here (commented in LogReader.cpp).

Thanks for any help on what C++ behaviors I'm missing that might be causing this!

EDIT: Not placing the `LogReader` into a vector removes the segfault (failing elsewhere now, but not a problem). The change is commenting the following line out in main.cpp

```
readers.push_back(&label_reader);
```

I guess now the question is why using std::vector is causing this problem.

---

LogReader.h

```
#ifndef LOGREADER
#define LOGREADER

using namespace std;

class LogReader {
     private:
         LogReader(){} // private default constructor

     public:
         ifstream *log_file; // file the log is read from
         vector<int> val_locations; // offsets in line for values
         string next_line; // next line from the file

         int current_time; // time for most recent reading
         string current_line;
         int next_time; // what is the next time in the file
         vector<string> current_vals; // what the current vals are

         LogReader(string log_loc, vector<int> offsets); // given a file to start on

         bool advance(int new_time); // advance the log reader, return true if advanced
         bool has_more(); // is there more in the log
 };

 #endif
```

---

LogReader.cpp

```
// c++ imports
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// my imports
#include "LogReader.h"
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

LogReader::LogReader(string log_loc, vector<int> offsets){
    // make the file reader
    ifstream lf(log_loc);
    log_file = &lf;
    // pull out the first line
    getline(*log_file, current_line);
    cout << current_line << endl;

    // get the set of current values
    val_locations = offsets;
    for(int i = 0; i < val_locations.size(); i++) {
        current_vals.push_back(get_line_part(current_line, 
                    val_locations.at(i)));
    }
    // get the current time
    current_time = stoi(get_line_part(current_line, 0));

    // pull down the next line
    getline(*log_file, next_line);
    cout << next_line << endl;
    // get the next time
    next_time = stoi(get_line_part(next_line, 0));
}

bool LogReader::advance(int new_time){
    if(new_time < next_time)
        return false; // nothing to do, current still good

    cout << "can check time" << endl;

    // update the time and values
    current_time = next_time;
    current_line = next_line;
    current_vals.clear();

    cout << "can do housekeeping" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < val_locations.size(); i++) {
        current_vals.push_back(get_line_part(next_line, 
                    val_locations.at(i)));
    }

    cout << "can push in new values" << endl;

    // move the line
    next_line.clear();
    if(!getline(*log_file, next_line)) {  // **SEGFAULT**
        // no more lines
        cout << "no more lines" << endl;
        next_line.clear();
        next_time = -1;
        return true;
    }
    cout << "got the line" << endl;
    // update the time as well
    next_time = stoi(get_line_part(next_line, 0));
    return true;
}

bool LogReader::has_more(){
    return next_time != -1;
}
```

---

main.cpp

```
// c imports
#include <time.h>

// c++ imports
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

// my imports
#include "LogReader.h"
#include "functions.h"

// custom shorter namespaces
namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

// used namespaces
using namespace std;

void update_line(int *current_time, string *current_line, 
        ifstream *current_file){
    if(!getline(*current_file, *current_line)){
        *current_time = -1;
        current_line->clear();
        return;
    }

    try {
        *current_time = stoi(get_line_part(*current_line, 0));
    } catch (int e) {
        cout << "update line, bad stoi on time" << endl;
        cout << *current_line << endl;
        throw e;
    }
}

void update_vals(vector<float*> vals, string line) {
    for(int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++) {
        // offset for fact that first two are time and sensor
        try {
            *(vals.at(i)) = stof(get_line_part(line, 2 + i));
        } catch (int e) {
            cout << "update_vals, bad stof for " << i << endl;
            cout << line << endl;
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

string get_correct_file(string name, vector<string> options) {
    for(int i =0; i < options.size(); i++) {
        string option = options.at(i);
        if(boost::algorithm::contains(option, name)){
            return option;
        }
    }

    return string("");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // open the base dir
    bfs::path base_dir("log/");
    if(!bfs::exists(base_dir) && !bfs::is_directory(base_dir)){
        cout << "Bad base directory" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // create a vector of the possible traces
    vector<string> traces;
    for(bfs::directory_iterator iter(base_dir);
            iter != bfs::directory_iterator(); iter++) {
        stringstream trace_path;
        trace_path << iter->path().string();
        traces.push_back(trace_path.str());
    }

    int trace_index = user_choose_option(traces);

    // load that directory
    bfs::path trace_dir(traces.at(trace_index));
    if(!bfs::exists(base_dir) && !bfs::is_directory(base_dir)){
        cout << "Selected a bad trace directory" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // get the image directory
    cout << "loading image directory" << endl;
    string img_path_string = trace_dir.string();
    stringstream img_path_stream;
    img_path_stream << img_path_string << "/img/";
    bfs::path img_dir(img_path_stream.str());
    if(!bfs::exists(img_dir) && !bfs::is_directory(img_dir)){
        cout << "no image directory" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // get image list, ends up in sorted order from naming conventions
    cout << "getting image paths" << endl;
    vector<string> image_paths;
    for(bfs::directory_iterator iter(img_dir);
            iter != bfs::directory_iterator(); iter++) {
        stringstream image_path;
        image_path << iter->path().string();
        image_paths.push_back(image_path.str());
    }

    // get the data traces
    cout << "loading data traces" << endl;
    vector<string> log_paths;
    vector<string> label_paths;
    string trace_path_string = trace_dir.string();
    for(bfs::directory_iterator iter(trace_path_string);
            iter != bfs::directory_iterator(); iter++) {
        string cur_file = iter->path().string();
        cout << cur_file << endl;
        if(boost::algorithm::contains(cur_file, "label-")) {
            label_paths.push_back(cur_file);
        } else if(boost::algorithm::contains(cur_file, "log-")) {
            log_paths.push_back(cur_file);
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    // temp for reading in line parts
    // istringstream temp;

    cout << "getting log readers" << endl;
    // choose the label file to use, get first line
    int label_index = user_choose_option(label_paths);
    vector<int> label_offsets;
    label_offsets.push_back(1);
    LogReader label_reader(label_paths.at(label_index), label_offsets);
    /*
    ifstream label_file(label_paths.at(label_index));
    string label_line;
    getline(label_file, label_line);
    int label_time;
    temp.clear();
    temp.str(get_line_part(label_line, 0));
    temp >> label_time;
    string label_current = get_line_part(label_line, 1);
    */

    /*
    // get the accel
    string accel_path = get_correct_file("accel", log_paths);
    vector<int> accel_offsets;
    accel_offsets.push_back(2);
    accel_offsets.push_back(3);
    accel_offsets.push_back(4);
    LogReader accel_reader(accel_path, accel_offsets);
    */

    vector<LogReader*> readers;
    vector<bool> updated;
    readers.push_back(&label_reader);
    updated.push_back(true);
//    readers.push_back(&accel_reader);
//    updated.push_back(true);

    int l_time = current_time_min(readers);
    while(label_reader.has_more() ){ // || accel_reader.has_more()) {
        // figure out what time to advance to
        int n_time;
        cout << label_reader.has_more() << endl;
        if(same_current_time(readers)) {
            n_time = next_time_min(readers);
        } else {
            n_time = current_time_nextmin(readers);
        }
        cout << n_time << endl;

        label_reader.advance(n_time);
        cout << label_reader.current_line << endl;
        /*
        // advance all the readers
        for(int i = 0; i < readers.size(); i++) {
            cout << "loop " << i << endl;
            // keep track of which values updated
            readers.at(i);
            cout << "can get from vector" << endl;
            bool advanced = readers.at(i)->advance(n_time);
            cout << advanced << endl;
            if(advanced) {
                updated.at(i) = true;
            } else {
                updated.at(i) = false;
            }
        }

        // sanity check printing
        for(int i = 0; i < readers.size(); i++) {
            cout << readers.at(i)->current_line << endl;
        }
        */

        // deal with statistics here

    }

    /*
    ifstream accel_file(accel_path);
    string accel_line;
    getline(accel_file, accel_line);
    int accel_time;
    temp.clear();
    temp.str(get_line_part(accel_line, 0));
    temp >> accel_time;
    float accel_current_x = stof(get_line_part(accel_line, 2));
    float accel_current_y = stof(get_line_part(accel_line, 3));
    float accel_current_z = stof(get_line_part(accel_line, 4));
    vector<float*> accel_vals;
    accel_vals.push_back(&accel_current_x);
    accel_vals.push_back(&accel_current_y);
    accel_vals.push_back(&accel_current_z);

    // get the sprox
    string sprox_path = get_correct_file("sprox", log_paths);
    ifstream sprox_file(sprox_path);
    string sprox_line;
    getline(sprox_file, sprox_line);
    int sprox_time;
    temp.clear();
    temp.str(get_line_part(sprox_line, 0));
    temp >> sprox_time;
    float sprox_current = stof(get_line_part(sprox_line, 2));
    vector<float*> sprox_vals;
    sprox_vals.push_back(&sprox_current);

    // get the lprox
    string lprox_path = get_correct_file("lprox", log_paths);
    ifstream lprox_file(lprox_path);
    string lprox_line;
    getline(lprox_file, lprox_line);
    int lprox_time;
    temp.clear();
    temp.str(get_line_part(lprox_line, 0));
    temp >> lprox_time;
    float lprox_current = stof(get_line_part(lprox_line, 2));
    vector<float*> lprox_vals;
    lprox_vals.push_back(&lprox_current);

    // get the light
    string light_path = get_correct_file("light", log_paths);
    ifstream light_file(light_path);
    string light_line;
    getline(light_file, light_line);
    int light_time;
    temp.clear();
    temp.str(get_line_part(light_line, 0));
    temp >> light_time;
    float light_current = stof(get_line_part(light_line, 2));
    vector<float*> light_vals;
    light_vals.push_back(&light_current);
    */

//    int time_current = min(label_time, min(sprox_time, 
//                min(lprox_time, min(accel_time, 
//                light_time))));

    /*
    // variables for processing here
    int total_time = 0;
    map<string, int> label_counts;

    while(label_time != -1 || accel_time != -1 || sprox_time != -1
            || lprox_time != -1 || light_time != -1) {
        time_current++;
        if(label_time != -1 && time_current > label_time) {
            update_line(&label_time, &label_line, &label_file);
            if(label_line.size() > 0) // if last label, don't overwrite
                label_current = get_line_part(label_line, 1);
        }
        if(accel_time != -1 && time_current > accel_time) {
            update_line(&accel_time, &accel_line, &accel_file);
            if(accel_line.size() > 0) // if last line, don't overwrite
                update_vals(accel_vals, accel_line);
        }
        if(sprox_time != -1 && time_current > sprox_time) {
            update_line(&sprox_time, &sprox_line, &sprox_file);
            if(sprox_line.size() > 0) // if last line, don't overwrite
                update_vals(sprox_vals, sprox_line);
        }
        if(lprox_time != -1 && time_current > lprox_time) {
            update_line(&lprox_time, &lprox_line, &lprox_file);
            if(lprox_line.size() > 0) // if last line, don't overwrite
                update_vals(lprox_vals, lprox_line);
        }
        if(light_time != -1 && time_current > light_time) {
            update_line(&light_time, &light_line, &light_file);
            if(light_line.size() > 0) // if last line, don't overwrite
                update_vals(light_vals, light_line);
        }

        // Processing happens here
        total_time++;
        if(label_counts.count(label_current) == 0)
            // not in map
            label_counts[label_current] = 0;
        label_counts[label_current]++;
    }

    // post processing happens here
    cout << "Labels Counts:" << endl;
    for(map<string, int>::iterator it = label_counts.begin(); 
            it != label_counts.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->first << " -> " << it->second << " -> ";
        cout << 1.0 * it->second / total_time << endl;
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior since you are using a pointer to an object that has been deleted.

```
ifstream lf(log_loc);
log_file = &lf;
```

`if` gets deleted when the constructor returns and you are still holding on to a pointer to the object.

Change `log_file` to an object instead of a pointer.

Comment: I'd made that change from the object to a pointer for another reason... but looking at the code now (it's changed a lot over the day) I don't think that was a good idea, or needed anymore.

This removes the segfault.